# How to connect two SCS and a proxy server via a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: java, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

We have a project that we have to build two self contained systems - Persons and Projects (some groups have to implement the persons and the others implement the projects- we have to implement the person). 
For each there is a separate data bank and they have to exchange information with each other. That is working with no problems (I think).

The problem arises with the docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    proxy:
        image: nginx:1.15-alpine
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        volumes:
          - ./proxy/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
          - ./proxy/conf/domain.conf:/etc/nginx/domain.conf:ro
        depends_on:
          - projekt
          - person
    # ========================================
    # Falls Sie das Person-SCS implementieren,
    # überschreiben Sie diesen Teil
    persondb:
        image: mysql
        environment:
          - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
          - "MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
          - "MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}"
          - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
        volumes:
          - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    person:
        #networks:
        #   - default
        build: ./person-scs/.
        depends_on:
          - persondb
        environment:
          - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
          - "MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
          - "MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}"
    # ========================================
    # Falls Sie das Projekt-SCS implementieren,
    # überschreiben Sie diesen Teil
    projekt:
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        command: -listen=:8080 -text="Hello from projekt"

    projektdb:
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        command: -listen=:3306 -text="I am just a dummy"
    # ========================================
```

The whole proxy-part of the docker-compose was given to us by our instructor, as well as the projekt and projektdb parts (because we don't implement the project SCS).

One of the instructions was, that no port other than 8080 will be visible "from the outside" and that we have to call out Person-API via "localhost:8080/person". As of now, when I call the localhost I get a Whitelabel Error Page with 404 message.

When I ignore the proxy server and implement a docker-compose inside my Person-directory (with the same Dockerfile) I have no problems seeing the localhost:8080/person page and everything works just fine.

They gave us no background in writing docker-compose files so I'm not sure what even to Google. Hope someone could give a tip.

Edit:

nginx.conf looks like that:

```
  user  nginx;
  worker_processes  1;

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
  pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

  events {
      worker_connections  1024;
  }

  http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        include /etc/nginx/domain.conf;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main; 

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            location / {
             proxy_pass http://person:8080/;  
            }
        }
  }
```

And the domain.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

   # Assets
   # location / {
   #     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   #     index  index.html index.htm;
   # }

    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;

   # set maximum allowed files
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /person {
        proxy_pass http://person:8080/;
    }

    location /projekt {
        proxy_pass http://projekt:8080/;
    }

}
```

I know that the `"...proxy_pass..."` part is in both domain.conf and nginx.conf files, it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Don't know if it's relevant, but I am using Spring boot as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a question really, that's a whole task.

First you need to understand how docker's bridge network works - it is setup automatically by `docker-compose` and all services declared inside file are included into it. You **dont** need to expose ports **between** services - inside network they are all exposed.

What you have to do is to expose ports to outside - in your case, according to the task it is `8080`. So, it will be the only entrypoint for your app. You exposed it from `web` - this is a mistake. If you have only one external port, grant it to `nginx`, and let `nginx` do internal forwarding to appropriate services inside bridge network.

You have to provide your `nginx.conf` for details, but in general it will look somehow like:

```
...
http {
  server {
    listen 80 default_server; # start listen on 80 inside network
    location / { # forward all requests ...
      proxy_pass http://web/;  # to "web" container
    }
}
```

Then you expose `nginx` to outside:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
nginx:
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

All ports of databases are used internally in your net, they should not be exposed.

Comment: Okay I understand that ports shouldn't be exposed, I deleted all of the unnecessary (see edited post) and I saw that a forwarding request already exists in the domain.conf file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the difference between `nginx.conf` and `domain.conf`? Your `domain.conf` looks full & correct; it makes all necessary redirections except I dont see `http{}` section there.  And, btw, are you sure, your `person` service listens for incoming connections on `8080`??

Comment: oh... could be that `person` is not listening.  I tried to add `command: -listen=:8080` or `ports:8080` but it doesn't do the trick.